# Sort Data by date in Asc in Access in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I want fetch data based on date in ascending. The code is fetching data but in wrong format e.g.:

```
14/02/2014
16/01/2014
17/04/2013
```

i.e dates is sort based on "dd" only month and year is not considered
the code is below

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Auto_Finance.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
con.Open();
string sql=@"select p.PName,p.hpno,c.Credit,C.Debit,c.Dates from Party_Det p inner join cd c on p.Loanno=c.Loanno order by c.Dates asc";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

But I want result like below

```
17/04/2013
16/01/2014
14/02/2014
```

I am using c# as front end and Microsoft Access as front end.

Comment: How about using `order by c.Dates asc` ?

Comment: sorry i can't get You Ji

Comment: that is from table cd. i just inner join two tables

Comment: I got the Answer. i just got the answer by changing the datatype in access file

Answer (score 1):

your query is

```
@"select p.PName,p.hpno,c.Credit,C.Debit,c.Dates from Party_Det p inner join cd c on p.Loanno=c.Loanno order by c.Dates desc"
```

as Gordon said
replace "`c.Dates desc`" by "`c.Dates ASC`"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string sql = @"select p.PName,p.hpno,c.Credit,C.Debit,c.Dates from Party_Det p inner join cd c on p.Loanno=c.Loanno order by c.Dates desc";
```

or this:

```
string sql = @"select p.PName,p.hpno,c.Credit,C.Debit,c.Dates from Party_Det p inner join cd c on p.Loanno=c.Loanno";
...
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Sort('Dates', SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: What's the change in the above query Ji?

Comment: @NagaRaj What is the type of `Dates`?

Comment: @NagaRaj Can you tell me `Not Working` means what?